# Google map suddenly stopped working, only for multiple markers

Tags: php, google-maps

I have a website where i list conferences. They are shown on a google map. I had two pages working well, one with all the conferences of the week (multiple makers) and another with only 1 conference. While i did not change the code, the one with multiple markers stopped working.

Here is the page that is not working anymore; www.biomeeter.com/index6fixed.php 
And this is the working page with only 1 marker; http://www.biomeeter.com/biologymeetingsdatabase.php?meeting_id=1060

This is the code for the multiple-positions. Somehow if i limit (not in the code below) the php results to only 1, the map works. So somehow there seems to be a problem in separation or something like that between markers... I can't figure out how to fix this, if there are any suggestions that would be awesome!

```
<div id="map" style="width: 550px; height: 370px;"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var locations = [

<?php


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM meetings WHERE YEARWEEK(start_date) = YEARWEEK(CURRENT_DATE) OR YEARWEEK(end_date) = YEARWEEK(CURRENT_DATE)");

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$lat = $row['langitude'];   
 $long = $row['longitude'];
  $name = $row['meeting_name'];
   $namewithoutbackspaces = str_replace("'", "", "$name");
    $meeting_id = $row['meeting_ID'];   
    $city = $row['city'];   
     $country = $row['country'];    
      $website=  $row['website']; 
  echo "['$namewithoutbackspaces </br> $city,$country </br> <a href=\"biologymeetingsdatabase.php?meeting_id=$row[meeting_ID]\"       target=\"_blank\" >more info</a></u>', $lat, $long, 1],"; 
   }

  ?>
  ];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 1,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.41885, 9.12166),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


var bioImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('gif files/index/marker.png',
  // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
  new google.maps.Size(21, 43),
  // The origin for this image is 0,0.
  new google.maps.Point(0,0),
  // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
  new google.maps.Point(20, 32));



var pinColor = "FA2222";
var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + pinColor,
    new google.maps.Size(21, 43),
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    new google.maps.Point(10, 34));


var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: bioImage
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebug says one of your locations has unescaped text.

Line 291, column 60 in the generated HTML. It's specifically the Xi'an China.

You'll want to escape the strings you are putting in that array.

Comment: Thanks Erik, that's an easy fix!